# Need to shut off a service when a call is coming in and when user dials a number

Tags: android, android-intent, android-context, telephony

So, I have a service that runs in the background (it's super secret so I cant tell you what it is:) ) but I need to be able to shut it off when the user initiates a call or a call is coming in. So far, I have checked out the `Intent.ACTION_ANSWER`, but for some reason, my Broadcast receiver never detects it. I have also tried to use the `PhoneStateListener`, but in my case statements, I am failing to understand how to do anything with my service. To what context is a `PhoneStateListener`?

Some example code for my `BroadcastReceiver`:

```
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {     
if (intent.getAction().equals(Intent.ACTION_ANSWER)) {
        phoneRinging = true;            
    }

Intent i = new Intent(context, MyService.class);        
    i.putExtra("phone", phoneRinging);
    context.startService(i);
}
```

Here is a snippet for starting a service via the `PhoneStateListener`.
Example: `startService(new Intent(---CONTEXT---, MySuperSecretService.class))`

And the receiver is in the manifest:

```
<receiver android:name=".PhoneReceiver" android:enabled="true">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.ANSWER"></action>
    </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

WTH goes into the `CONTEXT` portion in this statement if I am in a `PhoneStateListener`?

Answer (score 0):

Please check [ACTION_PHONE_STATE_CHANGED](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/telephony/TelephonyManager.html#ACTION_PHONE_STATE_CHANGED) instead of [ACTION_ANSWER](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#ACTION_ANSWER). ACTION_ANSWER is not broadcast intent for incoming call. It's a standard activity action.